# how to detect WifiConfiguration objects is created by my App or the user or by other apps

Tags: android, wifi, android-6.0-marshmallow

Wi-Fi and Networking Changes
This release(6.0) introduces the following behavior changes to the Wi-Fi and networking APIs.

Your apps can now change the state of WifiConfiguration objects only if you created these objects. You are not permitted to modify or delete WifiConfiguration objects created by the user or by other apps.
but how should we detect WifiConfiguration objects is created by whom??

Comment: Have you found the solution yet ? I met problem like you, and haven't found solution